# php environment variable not working on windows server 2012

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I am trying to add PHP directory in the path for the environment variable on windows server 2012 , clicked on **advanced system parameters** ->**environment  variables**->**system variables** and then added the following code to path  `c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\` which I am sure it contains the `php.exe`, but when I try to access `php -v` from `cmd` it says that it does not recognise the command . I wish you could help me with that . the entire path is as follows

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ ; c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\

Comment: Try removing the unnecessary spaces.

Comment: see this solution https://www.sunant.com/robots-and-rockets-blog/running-php-from-windows-command-line/

Comment: If you opened the `cmd` before changing the env vars then close it and open a new one. Running processes _won't_ get updated! Even better would be to reboot.

Comment: It has worked for me , it is the  unnecessary spaces. –thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Did you try c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10\bin ?